# jquery swap images on hover WITH caption

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have b/w images showing. When you hover over the image, it fades into color image which is a separate file (img-1.png and hover-img-1.png etc).
There's also a caption that should always show on top of the images as an absolute positioned div.

My problem is that the image does swap, but when I put the mouse over the caption, image goes back to b/w instead of staying in color.

What am I missing?

Here's the code I currently have:

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
    .galleryImg {
        float:left;
        margin: 10px 4px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .caption {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 15px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-size:14px;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    // wrap as a jQuery plugin and pass jQuery in to our anoymous function
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.cross = function (options) {
            return this.each(function (i) { 
                // cache the copy of jQuery(this) - the start image
                var $$ = $(this);

                // get the target from the backgroundImage + regexp
                var target = $$.css('backgroundImage').replace(/^url|[\(\)'"]/g, '');

                // nice long chain: wrap img element in span
                $$.wrap('<span style="position: relative;"></span>')
                    // change selector to parent - i.e. newly created span
                    .parent()
                    // prepend a new image inside the span
                    .prepend('<img>')
                    // change the selector to the newly created image
                    .find(':first-child')
                    // set the image to the target
                    .attr('src', target);

                // the CSS styling of the start image needs to be handled
                // differently for different browsers
                if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
                    $$.css({
                        'position' : 'absolute', 
                        'left' : 0,
                        'background' : '',
                        'top' : this.offsetTop
                    });
                } else if ($.browser.opera && $.browser.version < 9.5) {
                    // Browser sniffing is bad - however opera < 9.5 has a render bug 
                    // so this is required to get around it we can't apply the 'top' : 0 
                    // separately because Mozilla strips the style set originally somehow...                    
                    $$.css({
                        'position' : 'absolute', 
                        'left' : 0,
                        'background' : '',
                        'top' : "0"
                    });
                } else { // Safari
                    $$.css({
                        'position' : 'absolute', 
                        'left' : 0,
                        'background' : ''
                    });
                }

                // similar effect as single image technique, except using .animate 
                // which will handle the fading up from the right opacity for us
                $$.hover(function () {
                    $$.stop().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 250);
                }, function () {
                    $$.stop().animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 250);
                });
            });
        };

    })(jQuery);

    // note that this uses the .bind('load') on the window object, rather than $(document).ready() 
    // because .ready() fires before the images have loaded, but we need to fire *after* because
    // our code relies on the dimensions of the images already in place.
    jQuery(window).bind('load', function () {
        jQuery('img.fade').cross();
    });

    //-->
</script>    
</head>

<body>
<div class="galleryImg">
    <a href="some_link">
        <img src="images/img-1.png" alt="" title="" class="fade" style="background: url(images/hover-img-1.png);" />
        <div class="caption">This is Image 1</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="galleryImg">
    <a href="some_link">
        <img src="images/img-2.png" alt="" title="" class="fade" style="background: url(images/hover-img-2.png);" />
        <div class="caption">This is Image 2</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="galleryImg">
    <a href="some_link">
        <img src="images/img-2.png" alt="" title="" class="fade" style="background: url(images/hover-img-2.png);" />
        <div class="caption">This is Image 3</div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `div.caption` is covering the image and is not a child of the image on which the hover event handler is registered.

Wrap the `img` and `div.caption` in `div.Something` and register the hover handler on `div.Something` instead of the image. Or, actually,  you could just register the handler on the `<a>` that is already wrapping them ;)

Don't know how "correct" it is to modify the plugin to do this, but the quickest fix in this case would be to change

```
        $$.hover(function () {
            $$.stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 250);
        }, function () {
            $$.stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 250);
        });
```

to

```
        $$.closest('.galleryImg').hover(function () {
            $$.stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 250);
        }, function () {
            $$.stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 250);
        });
```

---

Update: Fixed by using `.closest('.galleryImg')` instead of `.parent()`.

Comment: sorry, but I'm a noob... I didn't write that code, I just c/p-ed it... Any chance you could post the entire code? Because I tried replacing as you said, but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: "No luck" means what? Same behavior, other incorrect behavior? Error(s)? It is really just adding `.parent()`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. No luck means I'm getting the same behavior. I added .parent() like you suggested, but it's still the same - my image goes back to b&w when I hover over the text. Am I crazy or what?

Comment: I just uploaded the files, you can take a look: http://promasaj.comuv.com/
Did I miss something or made some stupid mistake? :) Thanks

Comment: I don't know why that wasn't working as expected, it seemed quite buggy actually because the hover-in/out was being triggered in areas not covered by the caption as well... Maybe it's some special case for hover on `<a>` that I don't know about because the updated code using `.closest('.galleryImg')` works fine for me.

Comment: wooo-hooooo! this works like a charm. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Would you by any chance know why it's not working in Opera? Using latest 11.61. Actually, it's acting very weird. When I hover only a portion of the image changes to color and then when I leave the image it turns to color and fades to b&w...

Comment: Sorry, but no. Weird stuff. I would just try a different solution and hope the bug doesn't show up then as well. Maybe it would help to set the z-index?

Comment: Well, I'd love to use a different solution, trust me, but this is the only one I was able to find. I need it to swap two image, use fade, can't use css background images for the main image and must easily work with a gallery of 10+ images without assigning different classes for each. Would you happen to know of any such script? :) Oh, and, just tried z-index but doesn't change anything.